# How to continue to next operation when catch block exception is triggered in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

Ok I want to continue to the next operation if an exception is caught in my try catch block , consider the following code. Right now if an exception is thrown it returns back to the view with a message 'Duplicate Facebook post', in this case if the Facebook exception is thrown then the Twitter::post tweet will never execute I want the code to continue to the next operation. How do I do this?

```
            if (isset($token)) {
            try
            {
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
                $fb->post('/me/feed', ['message' => 'This is a test message']);
            }
            catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Duplicate Facebook post.');
            }
        }

        if(isset($twitterToken)) {
            try
            {
                Twitter::postTweet(['status' => str_limit($request->input('body') . ' SITE',137), 'format' => 'json']);
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Duplicate Tweet Posted.');
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Status Posted.');
    }
```

Comment: I'd try removing the `return` statements in the catch block because `return` usually `returns`.

Comment: And of course the world could not survive without yet another tweet

Comment: @tkausl of course, your right, can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks.